# Sort case insensitive in recent versions of Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

How can you do a case-insensitive sort in recent versions of Notepad++ (i.e. >= 6.5)?.

I'm aware of the old way of using TextFX, however Notepad++ now has the built-in "Line Operations", but these seem to be case sensitive.

Comment: Good answer here: http://superuser.com/a/777412/69589

Comment: @bradcupit Sorry, but this is the standard line sort that I mentioned in my question ... I'm after case insensitive sorting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Current versions now support this out of the box (tested with 7.9.1):

[image]

Comment: This was indeed implemented with v7.9.1 https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/4479

Answer (score 8):

You can still use the **TextFX Characters** plugin in recent versions of Notepad++ (tested under version 6.5.5):

- Click `Plugins/Plugin Manager`/`Show Plugin Manager`
- Under Available find `TextFX Characters`
- Click Install
- Select rows to be sorted.
- Click `TextFX/TextFX Tools`
- Check or uncheck `Sort ascending`
- `Sort lines case insensitive`

Comment: Yes, I was aware of the TextFx plugin (see my question), but it was dropped from Notepad++ at 5.9.8, and I thought its code had been folded into core

Comment: @SteveC Despite that, you can still use this plugin in the new version Notepad++ (v6.5.5).

Comment: TextFx is 32 bit only, and NP++ 64-bit can't use it

Answer (score 1):

Since N++ is trying to sort a text file, you can just save the file
and use the `SORT` command in a DOS window;
then just re-open the sorted file with N++ .

For help with the `SORT` command in a DOS window,
type either of the following:
`SORT /?|MORE`
`HELP SORT|MORE`

2019Feb25 (JoeG314)

Comment: This is THE BEST ANSWER to the case-insensitive sorting problem for text files.

Answer (score 0):

Case insensitive sorting is not supported in Notepad++. TextFX is not supported in recent x64 Notepad++, but will work for this in other versions.

Here's a convoluted workaround for most cases:

1. Load and enable the "elastic tabstops" plugin, if necessary.
2. Add a tab character at the end of each line (search/replace).
3. Copy the file as a column (Alt-drag).
4. Paste the column at the beginning of the file (duplicating each line horizontally, separated by a tab).
5. Select the left column, and from the Edit menu, Convert Case to, lowercase.
6. Do a Lexicographic Sort from the Edit menu.
7. Select and delete the left column.
8. Delete leftover tab characters.

Alternatively, you can copy and paste into something like Excel, sort, and copy back.