# Is there a way to sort case insensitively in Notepad++ 64 bit?

Tags: notepad++

To start: Yes I'm aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23606753/sort-case-insensitive-in-recent-versions-of-notepad) answer from over 6 years ago, but none of the answers would work inside of notepad++ x64 and I'm hoping that a plugin has came along that I have missed.

Things I've looked at and ruled out:

1. Using TextFX - Not available for 64 bit (and a bit overkill for just case insensitive sorting, but that's not nearly as important)
2. The builtin sort in Notepad++ - Case sensitive
3. Save the file and then run it through sort - This technically works, but requires saving and leaving Notepad++

Answer (score 2):

Takes three editing steps.
Use a regular expression to modify each line to have a lower case version of the original, a marker string, then the original line.
Sort the lines.
Remove the lower case text and the marker.

In more detail:

1. Choose a marker, a character or text that does not occur anywhere in the text to be sorted. For this example I will use `<<>>`.
2. Do a regular expression search and replace changing `^(.*)$` to `\L\1\E<<>>\1`. The `\L\1` inserts a lower case copy of the captured text. The `\E` stops the `\L`, the `<<>>\1` inserts the marker and the original text.
3. Perform a sort lines lexicographically ascending.
4. Do a regular expression search and replace changing `^.*<<>>` to the empty string, to leave just the original text.

For a clearer explanation of this technique see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60618065/546871).